# map function wont work what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to get the information in this array onto components! Not sure what im doing wrong!! Please save me. below is my array of stuffs

So i get my data from firebase then i do this to it

```
function snapshotToArray(snapshot) {
  var returnArr = [];

  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var item = childSnapshot.val();
    //item.key = childSnapshot.key;

    returnArr.push(item);
  });

  return returnArr;
};

export function allMyPropertiesDetailsFetch(currentscreen) {
  console.log("Called the property details");
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  console.log("gotthuser");
  console.log(firebase.database().ref(`/properties/`));
  var propertyref = firebase.database().ref(`/properties/`).orderByChild('userid').equalTo(currentUser.uid);

  propertyref.once('value', snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      var Property = snapshotToArray(snapshot);
      //     console.log('Property: '+Property);
      currentscreen.setState({
        propertyinfo: Property
      });
    } else {
      //  console.log('There is no user who has email like '+ email)
    }
  })

}
```

my array looks  [{"aptNumber":"","city":"","nickName":"","numberofbathrooms":"2","numberofbedrooms":"1","state":"","streetName":"","streetNumber":"","typeof":"Apartment","userid":"sb7Hj93D08XiaRguQ4cbSjz4vXC3"}] . STILL doesnt work im calling it like this .  var persons = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.propertyinfo));
  console.log(persons);

let added_buttons_goes_here = persons.map( (data, index) => {
     return (
         
             /// psedo code of pass-in remove button as a children
              this._handleRemoveButton(data.key) } />
         
     )
 });

Comment: Please add your code as well.

Comment: Why you add/need Object key in array. Please remove it

Comment: post your loop logic code...

Comment: Show me your fully the code. Map will not works when you have not sorting keys in array.

Comment: Please show your attempt so we can assist.

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just added stuffs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your array like this.

```
let array = [
 {
   "aptNumber": "",
   "city": "",
   ...   
 },
 {
   "aptNumber": "",
   "city": "",
   ...    
 }
]

console.log(array.map(x => x.key));
```

Comment: Acceptable, since the OP hasn't provided their logic for looping.

Answer (score 0):

The Json you are dealing with seems to be an invalid one. How do you generate this json object. If you are the one who generate this json in your services, then please try to create a valid json response.
I have formatted yours as below:

```
[{"aptNumber": "", "city": "", "key": "6bba4c82-18e2-3c10-a798-028f42d97857", "nickName": "My name ", "numberofbathrooms": "2", "numberofbedrooms": "1", "state": "", "streetName": "Fskslal", "streetNumber": "Fjsl", "typeof": "Apartment", "userid": "sb7Hj93D08XiaRguQ4cbSjz4vXC3"}, 
{ "aptNumber": "", "city": "", "key": "714590f6-e8da-2d29-20c2-e5010a3a9df4", "nickName": "BATMAN", "numberofbathrooms": "2", "numberofbedrooms": "0", "state": "", "streetName": "", "streetNumber": "", "typeof": "Apartment", "userid": "sb7Hj93D08XiaRguQ4cbSjz4vXC3"},
{ "aptNumber": "", "city": "", "key": "bd2ad46a-f307-4f8e-1fc8-ba828b6651bc", "nickName": "NOT BATMAN", "numberofbathrooms": "0", "numberofbedrooms": "0", "state": "", "streetName": "", "streetNumber": "", "typeof": "Apartment", "userid": "sb7Hj93D08XiaRguQ4cbSjz4vXC3"} ]
```

If you consume this json from other parties, then you will have to do some manipulations by keeping this as as String, but its not a clean way of doing/parsing a json response.

Comment: I figured it was the issue! Ill just take a look in the am! Im exhausted

Comment: my array looks  [{"aptNumber":"","city":"","nickName":"","numberofbathrooms":"2","numberofbedrooms":"1","state":"","streetName":"","streetNumber":"","typeof":"Apartment","userid":"sb7Hj93D08XiaRguQ4cbSjz4vXC3"}] .

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out guys

I was declaring in 
this.state{
propertyinfo:''}

when it should have been
propertyinfo:[]